# NSMutableArray UIButtons Action?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uibutton, nsmutablearray

I am  Creating `UIButtons` programmatically and Then Store these `UIButtons` in `NSMutableArray`. All these `UIButtons` have Some Text as Titles. I have No Outlet for These `UIButtons`. Now I want to Assign the Title of `UIButton` to `UIlabel` when I touch or Click some `UIButton`. But the problem for me is this: how can I perform the function on these `UIButtons`. Because I created `UIButtons` programmatically and also these `UIButtons` have No Outlet. Here is my code to create Buttons:

```
     saveBtn = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    for (int i=0; i<30; i++) {


        if (btnn>8) {
             UIButton *btn = [UIButton   
            buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
            btn.frame = CGRectMake(200.0 , spacey, 30.0, 30.0);
            int idx;
            idx = arc4random()%[arr count];
            NSString* titre1 = [arr objectAtIndex:idx];
            [btn setTitle:titre1 forState:UIControlStateNormal];      
            spacey=spacey+30;
            spacex = 80;
            btnn = 0;
            }
        else {
            btnn++ ;
            UIButton *btn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
            btn.frame = CGRectMake(spacex, spacey, 30.0, 30.0);
            int idx;
            idx = arc4random()%[arr count];
            NSString* titre1 = [arr objectAtIndex:idx];
            [btn setTitle:titre1 forState:UIControlStateNormal];   
            spacex = spacex + 30;
            [saveBtn addObject:btn];
            [self.view addSubview:btn];

        }
    }
```

Please any one can guide me how can perfom action for these `NSMutableArray` `UIButtons`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add actions to an UIButton programmatically using:

```
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

- (void)buttonClicked:(UIButton *)btn
{
    [btn setTitle:@"UnAutreTitre" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Dear i try it..thanx but my buttons store in Array so here how we can give the reference of my Array.bcz i want to perfom action on uibutton which is store in my array.

Comment: You know, there's [NSArray objectAtIndex:]... Seriously, please read the docs for such a fundamental question like "How to access nth element in an array"...

Comment: Thanx Dear your code is perfect for me .when i implement it before adding the UIButtons in Array..its work fine.so Thanx for you i solve my problem using your code.

Answer (score 1):

Simply set tag and add target to the button. Later, you can get which button was tapped.

Answer (score 1):

Create the action for the `UIButton` action, where you will be sending the `(id)sender` to the `actionButtonFunction`.

Assign sender to `UIButton` and then take the button title in `NSString`.

```
-(UIAction)buttonAction:(id)sender
{
    UIButton *button = (UIButton *)sender;
    NSString *buttonTitle = button.text;

    // further code goes here
}
```

Comment: thanx but my button store in Array so here how we can give the reference of my Array.bcz i want to perfom action on uibutton which is in my array.